# Ramanujan's Series for 1/pi - Finding 17,526,100 digits of a partial sum that coincide with 1/pi

Tags: sequences-and-series

It is kind of hard to summarize in the title alone. These questions relate to Ramanujan's series for $\frac{1}{\pi}$:

$$\frac{1}{\pi} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{8}(4n)!(1103+26390n)}{9801(n!)^4396^{4n}}$$

We [previously found and used](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1784708/72031) the following inequalities:

$$a_{n+1} < La_n$$
and
$$a_n< L^{n-1}a_1$$
and
$$0 < \frac{1}{\pi} - S_n < \frac{a_1L^n}{1-L}$$

My exact question I now need help with is:

*Use this estimate (referring to the last inequality shown above) to find as small an $n$ as possible such that the first 17,526,100 digits of $\frac{1}{\pi}$*

Here $S_n$ is the partial sum of the series, and $a_n$ denotes the $n$th term of the series ($S_0 = a_0$).

I am very confused as to how to go about this. As it is said in the question, i have to somehow use $0 < \frac{1}{\pi} - S_n < \frac{a_1L^n}{1-L}$ to do this, but I would have no clue as to how to do that. Even if I did, I am still confused as how you would know if any digits were correct at all without individually going through all of them? How is it possible to do this?

Does it have something explicitly to do with the remainder of the series from the partial sum ($\frac{1}{\pi} - S_n$)?

Hopefully I have put in enough detail for someone to be able to help.

Thanks

Comment: Guaranteeing that you had the smallest possible $n$ might be hard. But finding an $n$ that works should be straightforward. All you need is an $n$ such that $\frac{a_1L^n}{1-L}<10^{-17526100}$.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Why is the number of digits raised to the power of 10, and is negative? I don't really understand how this works. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You want the first 17526100 decimal digits to agree, so the error should be less than 1 in the last digit in other words at most $\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)^{17526100}$. As usual we often write $\frac{1}{k^n}$ as $k^{-n}$.

Comment: Thank you again. Unfortunately I am still a bit confused. So $10^{-17526100}$ is a number that starts 17526100 digits after the decimal place. It is obviously really small. I am confused why we make this greater than $\frac{a_1L^n}{1-L}$ though. I am also kind of confused why we can do this? Does it represent something I am missing or is it just doable because it has a solvable $n$ in it?

Comment: You need some way of approximating the error if you take only $n$ terms of the R series. All you seem to have is the upper bound $\frac{a_1L^n}{1-L}$. You have not said what $L$ is, but I assume it is extremely small.

Comment: Ok The strategy has been mentioned by @almagest very nicely. You also need to know the value of $L$ to a reasonable accuracy. As far as I am aware the value of $L$ is approximately $1/10^{8}$ and therefore roughly $n = 17526100/8 = 2190762$ But the kind of exact value of $n$ which your question is seeking may be difficult to figure out.